# parsing xml file with spanish (non UTF-8 format)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xml-parsing

I need to parse xml files in spanish (were I don't have control over how are being generated). the parsing part works just fine but the problem is when the xml file has special characters for example:

Espectáculos

when is parse I get this:
áculos

I'm using CocoaXMLParser. any of you knows how can this been handle ?

this is my code:

```
-(void)getRss
{
    NSString *urlString=@"http://mysite.com/content.xml";
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *rssRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    self.contentConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:rssRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


}




- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {


    self.dataResponse = [NSMutableData data];

    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_dataResponse appendData:data];

     NSLog(@"didReceiveData");




}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");

}



- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

     NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading ");

     [self parseContent];
}


-(void)parseContent
{
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_dataResponse encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"data received %@", response);
    NSLog(@"parse content ");

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:_dataResponse];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];


}


- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    self.currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"categoriaNoticias"])
    {
            self.validXML=YES;
        NSLog(@"es xml valido");

    }
    else
    {
         self.validXML=YES;
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (_validXML) {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"titulo"])
        {
            NSString *string=_currentNodeContent;
            NSLog(@"titulo %@", string);
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"link"])
        {
        NSLog(@"titulo %@", _currentNodeContent);
    }

}
```

}

I'll really appreciate any pointers

Comment: By standard, XML *must* be encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @mvp: "Each external parsed entity in an XML document may use a different encoding for its characters." from http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charencoding

Comment: I do understand but as I mention I don't have control over the creation of the xml file and I need to work with I giving to work

Comment: @Juan: well the document has some encoding, probably latin-1. If it's wrong or missing, maybe patch it in after you read it?

Comment: @Juan: What encoding does your XML file have? And how do you receive it and feed it to the XML parser? Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the code. That already helps a lot. But we should know as well what the effective encoding of your XML file is and if and what encoding declaration it contains on the first line.

Comment: The first line of the xml file look like this <rss version="2.0">. doesn't have enconding

Comment: Ok, but what is the effective encoding? Is it Latin-1, UTF-8 or something else? A good text editor will tell you.

Comment: @mvp It's only UTF-8 if no encoding is present, otherwise several are allowed. See: w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#NT-EncodingDecl

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your XML file is encoded in Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1), you fix the XML file on the fly:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    const char* xmlDecl = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>\r\n";
    self.dataResponse = [NSMutableData data];
    [self.dataResponse appendBytes: xmlDecl length: strlen(xmlDecl)];
}
```

Please check what the effective encoding is and adapt the accordingly if needed.

Comment: I have add the code above but now I'm getting: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> and nothing has been parse.

Comment: Then your XML file does not start with `<rss version=...` as you have written above in a comment. And you finally need to figure out what the effective encoding is.

Comment: @Juan Use this to find out the content type of the response `[[response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Content-Type"]` the value will be `text/html; charset=utf-8` for UTF-8, etc.